# Ignite web agent jdbc drivers not found

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I'm trying to play around with the automatic RDBMS integration. Following the directions in the ignite-web-agent readMe, I copied my postgres driver (42.2.5) into the jdbc-drivers folder.

Ignite and the console agent both started up fine, and the log output from the console agent is below:

[2019-02-12 02:13:10,678][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Starting Apache Ignite Web Console Agent...

[2019-02-12 02:13:11,631][INFO ][main][AgentLauncher] Connecting to: https://console.gridgain.com

[2019-02-12 02:13:12,070][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Connection established.

[2019-02-12 02:13:12,289][INFO ][EventThread][AgentLauncher] Authentication success.

[2019-02-12 02:13:12,664][INFO ][pool-1-thread-1][RestExecutor] Connected to cluster [url=http://localhost:8080]

[2019-02-12 02:13:12,710][INFO ][pool-1-thread-1][ClusterListener] Connection successfully established to cluster with nodes: [AE9ED479]

Anything I am missing? Any ports that I need to confirm are open?

I am running:
 - Cloud platform: AWS
 - OS: Windows Server 2019
 - DB: Posgres 11.1
 - DB Driver: PostgreSQL-42.2.5.jar 
 - Java: 1.8.x.202
 - Ignite: 2.7
 - Ignite-Web-Agent: 2.7.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. PostgresSQL server should run on same machine where Web agent launched.
2. Go to [console.gridgain.com](https://console.gridgain.com/configuration/overview) and click "Import from Database" (at the top-right corner). It will open "Model import" dialog where you should be able to import model from your DB in step-by-step wizard.
3. See [docs](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/automatic-rdbms-integration) (with a bit outdated screenshots, but general the same).

Hope this help.

Update 1.
  After some thoughts, I think #1 is not a "must have", but instead should be treated as "Web Agent should be able to connect to RDBMS via JDBC driver". Usually it is easy to do when Web Agent and RDBMS server run on same machine, but should work in more general case.

Comment: Didn't know the agent had to be on the db server, I will try that later and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Still having issues after running the web agent from the pg server. Same symptoms as before - web agent logs look correct, and I see the cluster on gridgain console

Comment: Just installed MySQL, and followed the same steps - didn't work either. Was watching the 'Using Ignite Web Console for Automatic RDBMS integration With Apache Ignite Part 1" video and followed the steps (except for the newer software versions).

Comment: Hi. 1. I updated my answer.  2. I do not understand - did you click "Import from Database" button? If yes, did you see dialog with wizard where you should select JDBC driver, user, and other option ?

Comment: Yep I figured the agent and rdbms did not have to be on the same server since you're able to enter a db connection string. So I repeated the same steps with pg and ignite on my local desktop (windows 10 pro) and it worked fine. Something about either (AWS) ports and protocols, windows server 2016 (where I have PG and the agent running) or windows server 2019 (ignite) appears to be causing issues.

Comment: I am willing to bet it is because I either still have a port closed, or web socket is not fully supported by default on windows server 2016/9. Certainly not on iis anyways, not sure about the rest of OS.